# ¿Es posible modificar el contenido del window.location sin que redireccione la pagina?

Tags: javascript

Necesito realizar una modificación del `window.location` entero (toda la ruta) sin actualizar. Algo similar al `history.pushstate`, pero no encuentro alguna forma viable de hacerlo

Intente realizar la modificación con el `definegetter` pero por lo que observo esta función solo sirve para los parámetros tipo document. 
**¿Es posible realizar modificacion del parametro location con javascript?**

Comment: ¿Podrías definir con más detalle que estás buscando realizar y por que `history.pushstate`no te es suficiente?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por favor mira en la ayuda [ask] , [qué puedo preguntar](/help/on-topic) y [qué no](/help/dont-ask). La pregunta tal cual la tienes ahora es muy amplia y es probable que sea cerrada. Te sugiero que la borres y cuando tengas una pregunta clara lo hagas con [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ¿Cual sería el problema que tienes al usar `history.pushState`?